# Thread.start is not found

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that I have created

```
List<String> list_of_stocks = Arrays.asList("AAPL", "NFLX");
StockThread stockthread = new StockThread(list_of_stocks);
stockthread.start();
```

and this`StockThread` is defined as:

```
public class StockThread implements Runnable {

List<String> list_of_stocks;

public StockThread(List<String> list_of_stocks){
    this.list_of_stocks = list_of_stocks;
}
@Override
public void run() {
        /*  So this thread simply has a */
        StockObserver so = new StockObserver(this.list_of_stocks, 1);

        so.getStockPrices();
 }
}
```

but the start() method of the stockthread shows up as 'could not resolve symbol'.

I do not understand what is to blame. This should be an accessible method as I have implemented runnable no?

Comment: You haven't shown how the `StockThread` class is declared, which makes it much harder to help you. Is it a subclass of `Thread`?

Comment: `Runnable` defines a method `run()` so you should not call `start()` but the former mentioned method

Comment: @Lino: Except if this is actually meant to be a different thread, calling `start()` *is* more appropriate, as calling `run()` would just execute the code in the same thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet of course, but as OP has mentiond to only have implemented `Runnable` the correct and only available method would be `run()`

Comment: @Lino: We haven't shown anything about what they've done, and given the name and the method they're trying to call, I would definitely not start recommending calling `run` directly without knowing more about the intention. That might compile but not do what the OP *wants* at all.

Comment: I am sorry @Lino, I put in the wrong snippet. It did implement runnable and the code is there.

Comment: Similar apologies to @Jon Skeet

Comment: above: @Lino I have just used the method run() so will call that and no errors are raised. this should be the right approach no? I was slightly confused because of ...https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html saying I should implement start instread of run()

Comment: You've linked to docs for `PreparedStatement`, which doesn't talk about threads at all. What are you trying to achieve? If you're trying to start a new thread, you probably want to call `new Thread(runnable)` and then call `start` on *that*. But as `StockThread` doesn't extend `Thread`, I'd also rename it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Here is the link to Oracle's Java tutorials topic: [Defining and starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to create threads and start them using the thread class `StockThread` is to use one of the following ways - an example:

A thread can be defined and started using two different ways:

1. Implementing the `Runnable` interface
2. Extending the `Thread` class

**1. Implementing Runnable:**

```
Public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to execude in the thread
    }
}
```

Instantiate and start the threads (two of them):

```
MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
Thread myThread1 = new Thread(runnable);
myThread1.start();
Thread myThread2 = new Thread(runnable);
myThread2.start();
```

The advantage of using the first approach is that the runnable class can still be extended.

**2. Extending the Thread class:**

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code to execude in the thread
    }
}
```

Instantiate and start the threads:

```
MyThread myThread1 = new MyThread();
myThread1.start();
MyThread myThread2 = new MyThread();
myThread2.start();
```

Note that any thread can only be started once.

Links to the APIs [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: your StockThread is implementing Runnable instead of extending Thread.

Runnable doesn’t have a start method.

You could rename StockThread to StockRunnable and use run.

This will compile but may not yield the expected result.

If you want multi threading to occur, calling the run method won’t work (as it will run the runnable in your current thread).

You can call new Thread(runnable).start() and this will cause runnable.run() to take place in a different thread. 
(Where runnable should be an instance of StockRunnable).

You may want to keep the instance of the thread you created to later test its state (for example, waiting for it to finish running).

Good luck!